# android : dont work repeat bitmap drawable

Tags: android, image, background, repeat

I need to set background of repeat image.
So i have a file `repeat_dark_bg.xml` in my drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/repeat_dark_marked"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    >
</bitmap>
```

`repeat_dark_marked` - image, which i want to repeat. 
so then i use `repeat_dark_bg.xml` as background value of my `linearlayout`.
but whats a problem.. when i test my app on device sometimes image  `repeat_dark_marked` repeat, sometimes it scales and resizes to full screen.. i cant understand why sometimes it shows this or that.. any ideas?

Comment: can you post repeat_dark_bg.xml code ?

Comment: i have posted it.. there is bitmap

Comment: Same problem here.. Please reply if you got a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

repeat_dark_marked.png is 9-patch ? make sure you dont have multiple repeat_dark_marked.png or repeat_dark_marked.9.png etc in your drawable folders. Check all drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi folders.

Comment: i have copies of this image in each folder : drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-ldpi, is it wrong?

Comment: No, that is fine. Each folder should have its own copy. But do you have any 9-patch file with same name "repeat_dark_marked" ?

Comment: no i havent.. i have only 3 images with that name in each folder